# find pattern print 2nd field and if not pattern print line without change using awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed, tcl

I have file in below format

```
addInst -inst RESET_n_RS  -cell PRWD_V ; placeInstance RESET_n_RS  4653.84 10212 R180 
addInst -inst MODE_RS  -cell PRWD_V ; placeInstance MODE_RS  4686.864 10212 R180 
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_4 -cell PVDD1_V  ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_4 4719.888 10212 R180 
addInst -inst VDD_IO_PD_T_5 -cell PVDD2_V ; placeInstance  VDD_IO_PD_T_5 4785.888 10212 R180 
placeInstance  DBG_RS 4861.728 10212 R180 
placeInstance  HAST_RS 4894.752 10212   R180 
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_8  -cell PVDD1_V ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_8   4927.776 10212   R180 
placeInstance  WIRE_RS 4993.776 10212   R180 
addInst -inst EN0_RS  -cell PRWD_V ; placeInstance EN0_RS  5026.8 10212 R180
```

If line has `PRWD_V` pattern, I want to print `$2` for that line and if pattern is not found in the line dont do anything print the line as it is.
The output as below:

```
placeInstance RESET_n_RS  4653.84 10212 R180 
placeInstance MODE_RS  4686.864 10212 R180 
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_4 -cell PVDD1_V  ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_4 4719.888 10212 R180 
addInst -inst VDD_IO_PD_T_5 -cell PVDD2_V ; placeInstance  VDD_IO_PD_T_5 4785.888 10212 R180 
placeInstance  DBG_RS 4861.728 10212 R180 
placeInstance  HAST_RS 4894.752 10212   R180 
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_8  -cell PVDD1_V ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_8   4927.776 10212   R180 
placeInstance  WIRE_RS 4993.776 10212   R180 
placeInstance EN0_RS  5026.8 10212 R180
```

I tried using awk

```
awk -F';' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /PRWD_V/) print $2} {print $1,$2}' file1
```

This is doing only for some lines and output is not coming properly.

Can we do the same in TCL also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `PRWD_V` always occurs in the first part of the line, as is the case in the sample input, then the solution could be as simple as:

```
awk '{sub(/.* PRWD_V .*; */,"")}1' file1
```

Explanation:

- `/.* PRWD_V .*; */` matches the first part of the line (including semicolon and surrounding spaces) *if and only if* that part contains the word `PRWD_V`.
- `sub(/.../,"")` removes the matched part from the line (*if and only if* there was a match).
- `1` prints whatever is left of the line.

Output:

```
placeInstance RESET_n_RS  4653.84 10212 R180
placeInstance MODE_RS  4686.864 10212 R180
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_4 -cell PVDD1_V  ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_4 4719.888 10212 R180
addInst -inst VDD_IO_PD_T_5 -cell PVDD2_V ; placeInstance  VDD_IO_PD_T_5 4785.888 10212 R180
placeInstance  DBG_RS 4861.728 10212 R180
placeInstance  HAST_RS 4894.752 10212   R180
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_8  -cell PVDD1_V ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_8   4927.776 10212   R180
placeInstance  WIRE_RS 4993.776 10212   R180
placeInstance EN0_RS  5026.8 10212 R180
```

The same effect can be accomplished with `sed` or even `grep`:

```
sed 's/.* PRWD_V .*; *//' file1
```

```
grep -oP '(.* PRWD_V .*; *)?\K.*' file1
```

Comment: Can we do same using TCL?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F' *; *' '{print (/PRWD_V/ ? $2 : $0)}' file
placeInstance RESET_n_RS  4653.84 10212 R180
placeInstance MODE_RS  4686.864 10212 R180
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_4 -cell PVDD1_V  ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_4 4719.888 10212 R180
addInst -inst VDD_IO_PD_T_5 -cell PVDD2_V ; placeInstance  VDD_IO_PD_T_5 4785.888 10212 R180
placeInstance  DBG_RS 4861.728 10212 R180
placeInstance  HAST_RS 4894.752 10212   R180
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_8  -cell PVDD1_V ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_8   4927.776 10212   R180
placeInstance  WIRE_RS 4993.776 10212   R180
placeInstance EN0_RS  5026.8 10212 R180
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed sed 's/.*PRWD_V[^;]*;[ \t]*//' input_file
placeInstance RESET_n_RS  4653.84 10212 R180
placeInstance MODE_RS  4686.864 10212 R180
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_4 -cell PVDD1_V  ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_4 4719.888 10212 R180
addInst -inst VDD_IO_PD_T_5 -cell PVDD2_V ; placeInstance  VDD_IO_PD_T_5 4785.888 10212 R180
placeInstance  DBG_RS 4861.728 10212 R180
placeInstance  HAST_RS 4894.752 10212   R180
addInst -inst VDD_PD_T_8  -cell PVDD1_V ;   placeInstance VDD_PD_T_8   4927.776 10212   R180
placeInstance  WIRE_RS 4993.776 10212   R180
placeInstance EN0_RS  5026.8 10212 R180
```